# Statistical test for difference in categorization method

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I have a set of integer that I am trying to see use different methods to categorize them into four groups, and the 2x2 table for the outcome of the 2 methods is displayed as below:

```
                method_B
     method_A   0   1   2   3
            0 182  11   0   0
            1  41 127   2   0
            2   0  12  18   0
            3   0   0   0   4
```

I am thinking of using `chisq.test` for comparing whether the difference in grouping distribution produced by 2 methods are likely to be caused by chance, but I am worrying about too many zeroes in the 2x2 table.

Should I use `chi.sq` test? Or is there any equivalent `fisher.test` for my case?

P.S. I tried `fisher.test` but it gives me `FEXACT ERROR 501`, which I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Try increasing the  `workspace` argument of `fisher.test`. That may avoid the error message, if your computer has enough memory (and you have enough patience). See `?fisher.test`. See my previous answer http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4023/chi-square-test-for-equality-of-distributions-how-many-zeroes-does-it-tolerate/4029#4029

Answer (score 2):

I don't think either chi-squared test or Fisher's exact test is useful here. It's pretty obvious that the results from method A and from method B aren't independent of each other. A statistic to *quantify how well* the two methods agree is more useful. The obvious choice is [Cohen's kappa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa).