# Goodness of fit between columns of a 10000x2 table (with low counts)

Tags: chi-squared-test, poisson-distribution, goodness-of-fit, contingency-tables, tables

I have a $10000\times2$ table (see below) where column **A** is made out of *observed data* and column **B** is the *output of a model* that I have which should fit the observed data **A**.

$n_{A}$ is the total number of points in column **A** and $n_{B}$ the total number of points in **B** and they are **not** necessarily equal.

```
A   B
-----
1   0
1   0
1   0
0   1
1   0
2   0
1   0
1   0
1   1
0   0
0   0
0   2
0   1
5   7
1   0
1   0
6   4
(...)
```

How should I characterize the *goodness of fit* of this model output (**B**) with  my observed data (**A**)?

The ***Chi-Squared*** test:

$\chi^{2}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$

(where $O_i$ is the observed frequency and $E_i$ is the expected frequency) has the issue of what to do I do if $E_i=0$? As you can see in the table above, there's **lots** of bins where $E_i$ is zero.

The same happens if I use a ***log likelihood Poisson*** test. This is how I've seen it expressed (taken from [here](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2004/reviews/statrpp.pdf)):

$-2ln\lambda=2 \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} (E_{i} - O_{i} + O_{i}ln\frac{O_{i}}{E_{i}})$

it will clearly have the same problem as the ***Chi-Squared*** test above, whenever $E_i=0$.

***Fisher's exact test*** was mentioned in the original question ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25946/goodness-of-fit-for-2d-histograms)) but later retracted.

So what can I do whit this table?

---

This question comes from [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25946/goodness-of-fit-for-2d-histograms) original post. I've tried to phrase it as simple as possible.

A very similar question was asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4023/chi-square-test-for-equality-of-distributions-how-many-zeroes-does-it-tolerate) but it was never fully answered.

Comment: Did you see that I extensively revised (again) my answer to the original question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25946/goodness-of-fit-for-2d-histograms, which may render this whole approach of using a contingency table of bin counts not necessary?

Comment: I'll go check it out right now. Thank you @PeterEllis.

Comment: Quite old question, but hopefully if you're still around, if your goal was to evaluate your model predictions against reality, maybe you'd be interested in this other question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225940/model-evaluation-for-discrete-regression